# Extract a specific character from shell output

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

When I execute:

```
root@imx6slzbha:~# iw wlan0 scan
```

I receive the following as output, it gives me multiple nearby SSID data.

How can I fetch Signal strength based on a specific SSID Name?

Currently, I am fetching based on BSS using this command:

```
iw wlan0 scan | sed -n '/bc:d1:1f:16:55:c7/,/WMM/p' | grep signal | sed 's/.*-//' | awk '{print $1}' | cut -d . -f 1
```

But I may not know the BSS each time so need a generic answer to this requirement.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUFNa.jpg)

```
BSS c8:00:84:85:41:b1 (on wlan0)
        TSF: 4138861160471 usec (47d, 21:41:01)
        freq: 2462
        beacon interval: 102
        capability: ESS ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x1421)
        signal: -80.00 dBm
        last seen: 90 ms ago
        SSID: Swarovski_Guest
        Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 6.0 9.0 11.0* 12.0 18.0
        DS Parameter set: channel 11
        Country: IN     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                Channels [1 - 11] @ 30 dBm
        ERP: <no flags>
        HT capabilities:
                Capabilities: 0x19ac
                        HT20
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 7935 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 8 usec (0x06)
                HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-23
                HT TX MCS rate indexes are undefined
        Extended supported rates: 24.0 36.0 48.0 54.0
        HT operation:
                 * primary channel: 11
                 * secondary channel offset: no secondary
                 * STA channel width: 20 MHz
                 * RIFS: 0
                 * HT protection: nonmember
                 * non-GF present: 1
                 * OBSS non-GF present: 0
                 * dual beacon: 0
                 * dual CTS protection: 0
                 * STBC beacon: 0
                 * L-SIG TXOP Prot: 0
                 * PCO active: 0
                 * PCO phase: 0
        Extended capabilities: 4, 6
        WMM:     * Parameter version 1
                 * u-APSD
                 * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
                 * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
                 * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
                 * VO: acm CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
BSS a0:ab:1b:cf:28:ae (on wlan0)
        TSF: 3196211626 usec (0d, 00:53:16)
        freq: 2462
        beacon interval: 100
        capability: ESS Privacy ShortPreamble ShortSlotTime (0x0431)
        signal: -74.00 dBm
        last seen: 80 ms ago
        Information elements from Probe Response frame:
        SSID: FOTA_Rashmi_2.4G
        Supported rates: 1.0* 2.0* 5.5* 11.0* 9.0 18.0 36.0 54.0
        DS Parameter set: channel 11
        Extended supported rates: 6.0 12.0 24.0 48.0
        Country: EU     Environment: Indoor/Outdoor
                Channels [1 - 13] @ 20 dBm
        TIM: DTIM Count 0 DTIM Period 1 Bitmap Control 0x0 Bitmap[0] 0x2
        WPS:     * Version: 1.0
                 * Wi-Fi Protected Setup State: 2 (Configured)
                 * UUID: 28802880-2880-1880-a880-a0ab1bcf28ae
                 * RF Bands: 0x1
                 * Unknown TLV (0x1049, 6 bytes): 00 37 2a 00 01 20
        ERP: <no flags>
        HT capabilities:
                Capabilities: 0x11ee
                        HT20/HT40
                        SM Power Save disabled
                        RX HT20 SGI
                        RX HT40 SGI
                        TX STBC
                        RX STBC 1-stream
                        Max AMSDU length: 3839 bytes
                        DSSS/CCK HT40
                Maximum RX AMPDU length 65535 bytes (exponent: 0x003)
                Minimum RX AMPDU time spacing: 4 usec (0x05)
                HT RX MCS rate indexes supported: 0-15, 32
                HT TX MCS rate indexes are undefined
        HT operation:
                 * primary channel: 11
                 * secondary channel offset: no secondary
                 * STA channel width: 20 MHz
                 * RIFS: 0
                 * HT protection: nonmember
                 * non-GF present: 0
                 * OBSS non-GF present: 0
                 * dual beacon: 0
                 * dual CTS protection: 0
                 * STBC beacon: 0
                 * L-SIG TXOP Prot: 0
                 * PCO active: 0
                 * PCO phase: 0
        Extended capabilities: HT Information Exchange Supported
        WPA:     * Version: 1
                 * Group cipher: TKIP
                 * Pairwise ciphers: TKIP CCMP
                 * Authentication suites: PSK
        RSN:     * Version: 1
                 * Group cipher: TKIP
                 * Pairwise ciphers: TKIP CCMP
                 * Authentication suites: PSK
                 * Capabilities: (0x0000)
        WMM:     * Parameter version 1
                 * BE: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 3
                 * BK: CW 15-1023, AIFSN 7
                 * VI: CW 7-15, AIFSN 2, TXOP 3008 usec
                 * VO: CW 3-7, AIFSN 2, TXOP 1504 usec
```

Comment: What do you mean by a generic requirement? How do you like to handle this then? Get input from user and print the value?

Comment: Please explain your current code. Please describe what you want to achieve. Are you looking for a fixed SSID? Which one?

Comment: Is your commandline supposed to have any output for the sample input?

Comment: Your "question" title is `Extract a specific character from shell output` so [edit] your question to at least tell us what that the specific character is you want to extract from the input you posted and why that is the character you want in terms of its relative location in the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order use a given SSID, e.g. "Swarovski_Guest" you can:

```
sed -n '/signal/h;/SSID: Swarovski_Guest/{x;s/^.*: -\(.*\) dBm$/\1/;p}'
```

- look for signal strength `/signal/`
- store it in history `h;`
- look for specific SSID name `/SSID: Swarovski_Guest/`
- retrieve the signal strength `x;`
- trim anything but the value number `s/^.*: -\(.*\) dBm$/\1/;`
- print it `p`

Output for sample input:

```
 80.00
```